# jQuery - Reset file input and update button on click

Tags: jquery

Only when a file is uploaded and `.submit` is clicked will the button change its HTML from `'Submit'` to `'Sent'`. I want to reset the button back to its original state after it has been cleared by clicking the `.reset` button.

The problem is I don't know how to clear the file and have the button reset it's html back to `'submit'`.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".submit", function(e) {
  var $uploader = $(this).closest(".item").find("input");
  if ($uploader.val() !== "") {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).html("Sent");
  } else {
    console.log("Please upload a file");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <div class="elements">
    <input type="file">
    <button class="reset">reset</button>
  </div>
  <button class="submit">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: So add clcik event and set the button text back? `$(".submit").text("Submit");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set value back to empty, like on any input filed you want to clear:

```
$uploader.val("")
```

And set the button back to same way you set it to `sent`

```
.html("Submit")
```

Also added code for reset button.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".submit", function(e) {
  var $uploader = $(this).closest(".item").find("input");
  if ($uploader.val() !== "") {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).html("Sent");
    $uploader.val("")
  } else {
    console.log("Please upload a file");
  }
});

$(document).on("click", ".reset", function(e) {
  var $uploader = $(this).closest(".item").find("input");
  var $submit = $(this).closest(".item").find(".submit");
    $submit.html("Submit");
    $uploader.val("")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <div class="elements">
    <input type="file">
    <button class="reset">reset</button>
  </div>
  <button class="submit">Submit</button>
</div>
```